# Reconstructing files coming on UDP with Rust pcap lib

Tags: rust, udp, libpcap

I am writing a small web service in Rust that listens to the UDP traffic, and writes the content into local files.
For that I use the [Rust pcap library](https://docs.rs/pcap/latest/pcap/).

I manage to listen to the stream and write to a file, but I would like to be able to detect that a file has finished to be streamed and the next one is starting.
So I thought to use a timer, to detect that if after e.g. 2 seconds of inactivity, I can close the current file, and start to write on the next one as soon as new packets are coming in.

However I cannot find a way to do that with pcap.

So far my code look like that. It listen to UDP and blocks after a message as been received, until the next message.

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    ...
    let mut cap = Capture::from_device(_device_name)
        .unwrap()
        .open()
        .unwrap();

    process_pcap(&pcap);

}
```

```rust
pub fn process_pcap<T: Activated>(cap: &mut Capture<T>) -> String {
    info!("Processing pcap stream...");

    let mut opened_file = open_new_file();

    while let Ok(packet) = cap.next_packet() {
        if let ControlFlow::Break(_) = process_packet(packet, &mut iq_open_file.file) {
            continue;
        }
    }
    info!("Done. Content available in {}", opened_file.path);
    return opened_file.path.clone();
}

fn process_packet(packet: pcap::Packet<'_>, file: &mut File) -> ControlFlow<()> {
    ...
    let _ = write_packet_data_to_file(file, payload);
    let _ = file.flush();
    ...
}
```

I thought about using the `nonblicking` mode (with `.setnonblock()` on the `Capture`), and reset a timeout each time a message arrives, but that seems a bit hacky.

Do you know if there are cleaner way to achieve this goal?